# subset sum with negative values in c or c++

Tags: c, algorithm, subset-sum

I have this code for finding the subset sum of positive values and everywhere I searched I only see positive integers or a program written in java in advanced level. I want to know how to implement that my C program would work with negative numbers. Actually, I want it to find sum that is 0. I had an idea

1. Take the minimum value in the set, call it `k`.
2. Add each element in the set by the absolute value of `k`.
3. Add sum by the absolute value of `k`.
4. Perform the algorithm.

---

But I found that this wont work. Take the set (-5, 10) and see if any subset adds up to 5. We would convert (-5, 10) -> (0, 15) and 5->10. -5+10=5, but 0+15 != 10

---

A lot of ideas I searched on the internet but can't find the answer.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int bool;
#define true 1
#define false 0

bool isSubsetSum(int set[], int n, int sum) {
    // Base Cases
    if (sum == 0)
        return true;
    if (n == 0 && sum != 0)
        return false;

    if (set[n - 1] > sum)
        return isSubsetSum(set, n - 1, sum);

    return isSubsetSum(set, n - 1, sum) ||
           isSubsetSum(set, n - 1, sum - set[n - 1]);
}

int main() {
    int set[] = { -3, 34, -2, 12, 5, 8 };
    int sum = 0;
    int i;
    int n = sizeof(set) / sizeof(set[0]);
    if (isSubsetSum(set, n, sum) == true)
        printf("Found a subset");
    else
        printf("No subset");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `typedef int bool; #define true 1 #define false 0` good lord, no. Pick **a** language, please.

Comment: this ain't c++ !

Comment: _But I found that this wont work._ [Does not work](http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/) is not an useful problem description.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *subset sum with negative values in c or c++*?

Comment: tbh I dont really understand what you want to do, but if you have an alogrithm that works for positive intergers you could simply add an offset to make all numbers positive and apply that one by looking for subsets of size 1 that add up to x+offset, subsets of size 2 that add up to x+offset*2, etc..., where x is the actual sum that you are looking for

Comment: I mean that for instance in this set {-1, -3, -2, 6 12, 48} I have to find that I can get a subset sum that is 0. -1 + -3 + -2 + 6 = 0. @chqrlie

Comment: Could you give me an example that I would understand it more clearly? Because I kind of understand but don't really know how it's made in a set. Thank you @tobi303

Comment: The OP is trying to write a function that determines if a given number can be the sum of a subset of elements of a given array of numbers.

Comment: Well, yes but I want it to be able to get to sum = 0. Because in this method without negative numbers according to recursion, the sum = 0 is always true.

Comment: Either the subset is allowed to be empty and sum=0 is always possible or the empty subset is not allowed and there may be cases without a solution for sum=0, such as `{ 1 }`.

Comment: "subset sum with negative values in c or c++" should be "subset sum with all possible integer values"

Comment: I updated it. I'm not searching for all positive. I am looking for negative. I changed my subset array values. @chux

Comment: "if any subset adds up to 5. ...  and 5->10." --> No, that last `5->10` should be `5-> 5 + n*offset` where `n==2` and `offset==5`.

Comment: Yes, now I understand but I will still have to figure out how to update my code. Thank you for explaining.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can try a brute force attempt by removing the test for overflow:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int isSubsetSum(int set[], int n, int sum, int empty_ok) {
    // Base Cases
    if (sum == 0 && empty_ok)
        return 1;

    if (n == 0)
        return 0;

    return isSubsetSum(set, n - 1, sum, empty_ok) ||
           isSubsetSum(set, n - 1, sum - set[n - 1], 1);
}

int main(void) {
    int set[] = { 3, 34, 2, 12, 5, 8 };
    int n = sizeof(set) / sizeof(set[0]);
    int sum = 6;

    if (isSubsetSum(set, n, sum, 0) == true)
        printf("Found a subset");
    else
        printf("No subset");
    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, the time complexity of this solution is **O(2<sup>n</sup>)**.

Here is a non recursive solution for sets up to 64 elements:

```
int isSubsetSum(int set[], int n, int sum) {
    unsigned long long last;

    if (n == 0)
        return sum == 0;

    last = ((1ULL << (n - 1)) << 1) - 1;

    // only find non empty subsets for a 0 sum
    for (unsigned long long bits = 1;; bits++) {
         int s = 0;
         for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
             s += set[i] * ((bits >> i) & 1);
         }
         if (s == sum)
             return 1;
         if (bits == last)
             return 0;
    }
}
```

Explanation: type `unsigned long long` is guaranteed to have at least 64 value bits. `bits` varies from `1` to `last` inclusive and takes all possible bit patterns of `n` bits except all off.  For each value of `bits`, I sum the elements for which the corresponding bit is set, hence all possible non empty subsets are tested.

Comment: I know but maybe this can be made by recursion? Still, thanks for the exaple

Comment: My main thing is that is has to work with sum = 0. However, Shows always that if sum = 0, ten found subset.

Comment: @AdomasArabella: here is a non recursive solution for up to 64 elements.

Comment: The subset can be empty. It is the purpose of my program to find empty sum. I mean, set {-1, -3, -2, 6 12, 48} I have to find that I can get a subset sum that is 0. -1 + -3 + -2 + 6 = 0.

Comment: If the subset can be empty, it is always a solution for a sum of 0.

Comment: You must specify if the subset can be empty or not. I updated the code for non empty solutions only.

Comment: Nice. Now it works. Really great. Can you explain what unsigned long long bits are because I'm new to c and this looks rather interesting.

Comment: Type `unsigned long long` is guaranteed to have at least 64 value bits. `bits` varies from `1` to `last` inclusive and takes all the possible bit patterns of `n` bits.  For each value, I sum the elements for which the corresponding bit is set, hence all possible subsets are tested.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I dont really understand your strategy. You should not use the absolute value. The sum of `a+b` has little to do with the sum of `|a|+|b|` (well there are some relations, but if you use them somewhere then I missed it ;).

If you have an algorithm that can find you a subset among positive integers that adds up to `x`, then you can use it also for negative numbers. It wont be as efficient, but with a small trick it can work....

First you add an offset to all numbers to make them all positive. Now you look for subsets that add up to `x+y*offset`, where `y` is the size of the subset. Eg. you have

```
A = -1, -3, -2, 6 12, 48
```

and you are looking for a subset that adds up to `0`, then you first add 3 to all numbers,

```
b = 2, 0, 1, 9, 15, 51
```

and then try to find a subset of size `1` that adds up to `3`, a subset of size `2` that adds up to `6`, ...., a subset of size `4` that adds up to `12`, that would be

```
12 = 2+0+1+9    ie    0 = -1 + -3 + -2 + 6
```

Doing it that way isnt very efficient, because you have to apply the algorithm `N`-times (`N`= size of input). However, if your algorithm for positives lets you fix the size of the subset, this may compensate this loss in efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

Code has TBD bug

Yet OP requested it to remain.  I fix it later or take down tomorrow.

---

OP's code has trouble because it is searching for the wrong `sum`.

By finding the minimum value and offsetting each element of `set[]`, the problem becomes one of only positive numbers - which apparently OP has solved prior.

The trick is that the target `sum` needs to be offset by `n*offset`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
//typedef int bool;
//#define true 1
//#define false 0

bool isSubsetSum(int set[], int n, int sum, int offset) {
    // Base Cases
    if ((sum  + n*offset) == 0)
        return true;
    if (n == 0 && (sum  + n*offset) != 0)
        return false;

    if (set[n - 1] > sum + n*offset)
        return isSubsetSum(set, n - 1, sum, offset);

    return isSubsetSum(set, n - 1, sum, offset) ||
           isSubsetSum(set, n - 1, sum - set[n - 1], offset);
}

int main() {
    int set[] = { -3, 34, -2, 12, 5, 8 };
    int sum = 0;
    int i;
    int n = sizeof(set) / sizeof(set[0]);
    int min = -3;  // TBD code to find minimum
    for (i = 0; i<6; i++) set[i] -= min;

    if (isSubsetSum(set, n, sum, -min) == true)
        printf("Found a subset");
    else
        printf("No subset");
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
Found a subset
```

Comment: Maybe I'm not seeing something but when I enter { -3, 34, -1, 12, 6, 8 } it still shows that subset found.

Comment: I was going on the assumption your code worked for positive numbers.  I'll take this down in a bit.  IAC, it is a lot like this good [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43078600/2410359)

Comment: Don't take down. my code worked but It didn't for 0 and negative numbers. Your code is pretty much what I was looking for. Maybe a couple  fixes may improve it.